# How to easily combine many vectors into a dataframe?

Tags: r, vector, for-loop, dataframe

I know that I can use the data.frame command to combine multiple vectors into one dataframe, like so:

```
my.data <- data.frame(name1, age1, name20, age20, name38, age38)
```

(I know, the variable names don't make much sense, why would I want name1, name20 and name38 in three different columns? Please ignore that: my actual variable names are different -- this is only for illustration purposes).

Problem is, I have about 40 of such vectors, and I have to combine many vectors in other parts of my code as well. So it would be convenient for me not to copy-paste a huge chunk of code every time. So I thought of writing a for loop around this:

```
for (i in c("name", "age", "hgt"))
{
    for (k in c(1,20,38))
    {
    my.data$i,as.character(k) <- data.frame(get(paste(i,as.character(k),sep="")))
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work. Is this because I should write "paste()" around some of this code, or is this simply a bad way to approach this problem? What is the correct way to loop through i and k and get a "newdata" dataframe as the final result with all the vectors as columns attached?

Comment: Why not change the code that creates all these vectors to instead create them as a data.frame to start with?

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to achieve something like the following, perhaps?

```
name1 <- letters[1:10]
age1 <- 1:10
name20 <- letters[11:20]
age20 <- 11:20
name38 <- LETTERS[1:10]
age38 <- 21:30

paste.pattern <- paste(rep(c("name", "age"), times = 3), 
                       rep(c(1, 20, 38), each = 2), sep = "")

newdata <- data.frame(sapply(paste.pattern, get))
```

Comment: Yes, this works well, although the other answer seems more flexible because I don't have to specify the reps

Comment: It's easier to just do `paste.pattern <- outer(c("name", "age"), c(1,20,38), paste0)` for the first part.  Or alternatively, `paste.pattern <- do.call(paste0, expand.grid(c("name", "age"), c(1,20,38)))`.

Answer (score 2):

If all your individual vectors have a similar stem (eg: `hgt`) and number (e.g. `1`) arrangement, then you could do something like this:

```
# test data
name1 <- letters[1:10]
age1 <- 1:10
name20 <- letters[11:20]
age20 <- 11:20
name38 <- LETTERS[1:10]
age38 <- 21:30

# group them up in a dataframe looking for "age" OR (|) "name" as the stem
data.frame(sapply(ls(pattern="^age[0-9]+$|^name[0-9]+$"),get))

# result:
   age1 age20 age38 name1 name20 name38
1     1    11    21     a      k      A
2     2    12    22     b      l      B
3     3    13    23     c      m      C
4     4    14    24     d      n      D
5     5    15    25     e      o      E
6     6    16    26     f      p      F
7     7    17    27     g      q      G
8     8    18    28     h      r      H
9     9    19    29     i      s      I
10   10    20    30     j      t      J
```

This will limit the included vectors to the stem/number naming pattern to make sure you don't get any surprise additions to your dataframe.

Comment: This works great! However, when I run it on my own data, the first column of the new dataframe is called "get.paste.i..._in...as.character.k....m...sep......". Do you know what is happening here? The individual vectors don't have this variable name anywhere. PS. The contents is simply a counter (rows). So now I am removing that column again afterwards, with newdata[,c(1)] <- NULL

Comment: @user1780218 - I have made a couple of edits to the line of code so that it is more strict in it's selection. The vector names have to start with the stem and end straight after the number now. That should solve any unintended matches.