# Identify and cbind multiple vectors based on vector name

Tags: r, vector, cbind

I have 100 numeric vectors named sim1 to sim100 in my workspace, all of the same length (18). I'm trying to find a way to identify them and cbind them to create a data frame of 18 rows and 100 columns. I can easily create a character vector of length 100 that contains the names of the vectors:

```
myvector<-ls()
myvector<-[grep("sim",myvector)]
```

..but I'm stuck on how to create a list of the objects themselves that I assume I could then use with do.call. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Similar, maybe a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13105888/in-r-how-to-easily-combine-many-vectors-into-a-dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
 do.call(cbind.data.frame, mget(paste0('sim', 1:100)))
```

Or as @Frank mentioned in the comments

```
 data.frame(mget(paste0('sim', 1:100)))
```

Comment: Is `data.frame` the same as `cbind.data.frame` here, effectively? Actually, I guess `as.data.frame(mget(...))` also works.

Comment: @Frank It is the same, but I started with `cbind`, and then changed to `cbind.data.frame`.  Also, `data.frame(mget(...))`

Comment: Thanks for these answers. Really useful.